# How to link to a restful Resource within a Blade template in Laravel?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to figure out the "Laravel" way of referring to a resource link from within a blade template.

The context is a CRUD Admin Panel I'm building. The URLs are as follows:

```
"list" camera resources:
  /admin/cameras

"show" a camera resource:
  /admin/cameras/12
```

These are working fine.

My routes.php:

```
Route::resource('admin/cameras', 'MyAdmin\\Controllers\\CamerasController');
```

In the template for the "list" action, I'm trying to add a link on each row to go to the "show" action for that resource. My current working code in views/cameras/index.blade.php:

```
<span>{{ link_to('/admin/cameras/'.$r['id'], $v); }}</span>
```

...where $r is the 'iterator' from the enclosing loop. Naturally this generates a url like the "show" above.

It seems a cleaner way would be to use link_to_route or link_to_action, but I haven't had much luck with either. Based on what I've read so far it doesn't seem possible to setup a named route on a resource. Is the code above optimal or does Laravel have something more elegant to offer here?

NOTE: I've seen some similar questions, but mine is specific to 'resource' routes.

Comment: If you look at http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers Laravel will assign route name to your resource. So your show route will be something like `link_to_route('admin/cameras.show', $v, array('id' => $r['id']))`

Comment: @JofryHS: Ah, I missed that names are already assigned. If you post as an answer I'll check as the official answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention as well, it'll probably a good practice for you to prefix your route as well, if few of them starts with `/admin/`. http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing Enjoy coding. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers Resource-ful routes are automatically assigned route names:

```
+-----------+---------------------------+---------+------------------+
|   Verb    |           Path            | Action  |    Route Name    |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------+------------------+
| GET       | /resource                 | index   | resource.index   |
| GET       | /resource/create          | create  | resource.create  |
| POST      | /resource                 | store   | resource.store   |
| GET       | /resource/{resource}      | show    | resource.show    |
| GET       | /resource/{resource}/edit | edit    | resource.edit    |
| PUT/PATCH | /resource/{resource}      | update  | resource.update  |
| DELETE    | /resource/{resource}      | destroy | resource.destroy |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------+------------------+
```

Hence if your resource name is `admin/cameras`, you'll just need to substitute `resource` with `admin/cameras`

And to generate the link to the route:

```
link_to_route('admin/cameras.show', $v, array('id' => $r['id']))
```

Comment: `route('admin/cameras.show', array()` is how you do it now

Answer (score 0):

You can simple state

```
Route::[action]('admin/cameras',array('as' => 'name.route','uses' => function(){ }))
```

then you can do like

```
link_to_route('name.route',$title,$paramerter=array(),$attirbutes=array())
```